# Incorrect screen height after setRequestedOrientation

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to force my layout to be in landscape for tablets, so I have this code:

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

But if I immediately call **getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels** after this call, it returns height of the tablet rather than width. Only after **onConfigurationChanged** is called I start to get correct height which happens after my main layout is inflated using incorrect screen dimensions.

I tried doing this after setRequestedOrientation:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = dm.heightPixels;
int width = dm.widthPixels;
dm.heightPixels = width;
dm.widthPixels = height;
getResources().updateConfiguration(getResources().getConfiguration(), dm);
```

This didn't helped though.

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

P. S. Even though I set orientation to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, I keep getting SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER after changes take place. Why is that?

Comment: Do you want the actual screen size or the UI screen size?

Comment: I think display metrics returns UI screen size without navigation bar with back button, so this is what I would prefer

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your code calculates the width and height before the layout is set. There is a thing called ViewTreeObserver which only lets you calculate after the layout is set.

A sample code

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```

Comment: I want to get height of the screen available for layouts, not the height of layout. It's already available, just somewhat height and width is switched.

Comment: okay height of screen can be given by DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

Comment: If you reverse the width and height part you can know of landscape

Comment: That's what I'm already doing, but that seems like a hack, because width and height changes once onConfigurationChanged is called

Answer (score -1):

have you added `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in your activity tag in manifest ? If not please add and try again